# Error with GUIDE opening in matlab

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, matlab-guide, fish

when i opening new blank GUI using

```
guide
```

I am receiving following error

```
Error using copyfile
fish: Unknown command ' -r --preserve=timestamps,mode -f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/toolbox/matlab/guide/guitemplates/guidetemplate0.fig
/tmp/tp95850ac1_4096_4622_a4d3_8674e8f55640.fig'
Error in guidetemplate/processDialogResult (line 168)
                    copyfile(srcfigfile, targetfigfile, 'writable');
Error in guidetemplate/dialogCallback (line 103)
                processDialogResult(quickstartpanel);
Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback.
```

I am running matlab R14b on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

How to fix it ?

Comment: Impossible to say without code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fish differs from other shells in that it is explicitly not POSIX compliant. Among other things this means fish doesn't split strings into tokens on whitespace boundaries when other shells (e.g., bash) would do so. This makes fish scripts simpler and safer but can lead to problems like this when a different program assumes $SHELL is POSIX compliant. The simplest solution is to tell matlab to use /bin/sh; either by doing

```
env SHELL=/bin/sh matlab
```

or via its configuration files.